# Showing $\ker(\phi)$ is a $\mathfrak{g}$-invariant subspace of $V$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, lie-algebras

Let $\phi:V\to W$ be a linear map between the irreducible $\mathfrak{g}$-modules $V,W$.

I want to show that $\ker(\phi)$ is a $\mathfrak{g}$-invariant subspace of $V$ and $\text{im}(\phi)$ is a $\mathfrak{g}$-invariant subspace of $W$.

---

First we show that $\ker(\phi)$ is a subspace of $V$.

$a,b\in \ker(\phi)$ then $\phi(a)=\phi(b)=0$ and then $\phi(a)+\phi(b)=\phi(a+b)=0\implies a+b\in \ker(\phi)$. Also $\forall a\in \Bbb F, b\in \ker(\phi) \implies a\phi(b)=0\implies \phi(ab)=0$

So $\ker(\phi)$ is a subspace of $V$.

Now showing it is $\mathfrak{g}$-invariant, I believe, means to show that $\mathfrak{g}(\ker(\phi))\subseteq \ker(\phi)$. Where $\mathfrak{g}(\ker(\phi))=\{w\in V: w=xv,x\in \mathfrak{g},v\in V\}$

**Not super sure here**
Now first, $x\in \mathfrak{g}$ means $x$ is a vector and this is defined as a left $\mathfrak{g}$-module and this is left multiplication, so we are 'multiplying' $x$ and $v$, both vectors. So first we have to worry about compatibility, and secondly, I can't just take $\phi(xv)=x\phi(v)=0$ to get this in the kernel, since $x\not\in \Bbb F$ right?

Comment: You   need that $\phi$ is a morphism of $\mathfrak{g}$ -modules which is exactly saying that $\phi(xv)=x\phi(v)$ for all $x\in\mathfrak{g}$ and $v\in V$. If you don't have this then there is no reason to have that $Ker(\phi)$ is a $\mathfrak{g}$-invariant module ($Im(\phi)$ same thing...).

Comment: @ClémentGuérin If $\phi$ is an intertwiner, such that for $\rho_1,\rho_2$, representations for $V$ and $W$, $\phi\circ\rho_1(x)=\rho_2\circ\phi(x)$, $\rho_i$ are both morphisms, would this bridge the gap?

Comment: Yes it would, after this, this is quite mechanical, btw, I am not sure you need at this point that $V$ and $W$ are irreducible... (unless you want to prove Schur's lemma after this).

Comment: @ClémentGuérin Oh I sure do, I proved Schur's lemma taking the above statement for granted earlier, and I realized I didn't know how to prove this. Hopefully I can work this out using the intertwining property. Thanks